# Displaying an JS Object in JSON from PokeAPI for DiscordBot

Tags: node.js, json, discord, pokeapi

I am trying to work on my discord bot and get information from the PokeApi, specifically the movelists of pokemon. I have the following code, but Im struggling figuring out how to get the movelist for each pokemon.

```
client.on('message',(async message =>{
    const args = message.content.toLowerCase().slice(poke.prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    if(!message.content.startsWith(poke.prefix))return;
    if(args[0] === "api"){
        const fetch = require ('node-fetch');
        fetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/25')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => message.channel.send(data.name.moves.move.name))
        .catch(err => message.reply('that spell does not exist!'));}}))
```

Now I know Im specifying a specific pokemon here (number 25), which is fine because I can change that later but this is the part that seems to be setting me back:

```
.then(data => message.channel.send(data.name.moves.move.name))
```

Also is there a clean way to create an embed with the data. Do I have to make a variable that has information or could I use "res"?

Any help or guidance with this is greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Looking at the API response myself, it looks like the moves would be under `data.moves` (an array) and then each item in that has a `.name` attr. Is that all you're having trouble with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you're slicing data off the API is incorrect. There *is no* `data.name.moves.move.name` in the response, so reading it will cause the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'move' of undefined
```

Instead, the response looks more like the following (with only the relevant bits shown):

```json
{
  "name": "pikachu",
  "moves": [
    {
      "move": {
        "name": "mega-punch",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move/5/"
      }
    },
    {
      "move": {
        "name": "pay-day",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move/6/"
      }
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

So, depending on what you want to do with the moves, you would need to massage the array of moves into the format you want. For example, to give them back a comma-separated list of moves, try the following:

```js
fetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/25')
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => {
    // Convert to `string[]` of move names
    const moves = data.moves.map(moveData => moveData.move.name);
    // Send message with a comma-separated list of move names
    message.channel.send(moves.join(','));
  });
```

As far as creating embeds, these are fairly easy to build up following the [Embed Structure documentation](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#embed-object):

```
fetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/25')
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => {
    // Convert to `string[]` of move names
    const moves = data.moves.map(moveData => moveData.move.name);
    // Send message with embed containing formatted data
    message.channel.send({
      embeds: [{
        // Set embed title to 'pikachu'
        title: data.name,
        // Add embed field called 'moves', with comma-separated list of move names
        fields: [{
          name: 'Moves',
          value: moves.join(','),
        }],
      }],
    });
  });
```